# Add Alternate ID field to the Inventory ID selector on the SOLine grid

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add the Alternate ID field from to the search selector on the SOLine details grid.  My code is as follows:

```
    [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
public class SO_SOLine_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
{
  #region InventoryID
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<InventoryItem.inventoryCD, LeftJoin<INItemXRef, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<INItemXRef.inventoryID>>>>),

        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.INItemXRef.alternateID),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.descr),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemClassID),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemStatus),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.itemType),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.baseUnit),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.salesUnit),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.purchaseUnit),
        typeof(PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem.basePrice))]
   public int? InventoryID { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
     public void SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

This adds the Alternate ID field to the selector and briefly, maybe for a second, returns the proper Inventory CD when selected, but then the Inventory CD changes the the integer ID which, of course raises an error indicator since the ID is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George, there is one-to-many relationship between the InventoryItem and the INItemXRef DACs - adding the PX.Objects.IN.INItemXRef.alternateID BQL-field into declaration of the PXSelectorAttribute is not enough to accomplish the task.

1. Declare unbound text field for the InventoryItem DAC to store Alternate IDs for each inventory item:

   ```
   public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<InventoryItem>
   {
       #region AlternateIDs
       public abstract class alternateIDs : IBqlField { }

       [PXString]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate IDs")]
       public virtual string AlternateIDs { get; set; }
       #endregion
   }
   ```
2. Subscribe to RowSelecting event (with mandatory use of PXConnectionScope to establish another connection with database) within the SOOrderEntry BLC extension to concatenate Alternate IDs for each line and populate unbound AlternateIDs field with calculated string value:

   ```
   public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
   {
       public override void Initialize()
       {
           Base.RowSelecting.AddHandler<InventoryItem>((sender, e) =>
           {
               InventoryItem item = e.Row as InventoryItem;
               if (item == null) return;

               string alternateIDs = string.Empty;
               using (new PXConnectionScope())
               {
                   foreach (INItemXRef crossRef in PXSelect<INItemXRef,
                       Where<INItemXRef.inventoryID, Equal<Required<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>.Select(Base, item.InventoryID))
                   {
                       alternateIDs = string.IsNullOrEmpty(alternateIDs) ?
                           crossRef.AlternateID : alternateIDs + "; " + crossRef.AlternateID;
                   }
               }
               item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>().AlternateIDs = alternateIDs;
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. Launch Layout Editor for the Sales Orders screen (SO301000) and select Edit Aspx option from the Actions menu:
   [image]
4. In Aspx file locate declaration of the InventoryID selector:

   ```
   <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges=“True" ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" AllowEdit="True" />
   ```
5. For the InventoryID selector, set FastFilterFields property to `AlternateIDs` and append columns by declaring the AlternateIDs column, then click Generate Customization script:

   ```
   <px:PXSegmentMask CommitChanges="True" ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" AllowEdit="True" >
       <GridProperties FastFilterFields="AlternateIDs">
           <Columns>
               <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AlternateIDs" AutoGenerateOption="Add" Width="250px" />
           </Columns>
       </GridProperties>
   </px:PXSegmentMask>
   ```

Comment: Thanks to you both for the answers.
Patrick - The substitute Key returns the correct InventoryCD but I then get an error thet the InventoryID does not exist in the system.
Ruslan - For my customer's purposes, I need InventoryID's repeated with a seperate AlternateID for each record in the selector.  I have tried repeatedly, but as I am sure you are already aware, I have not been able to modify the code you supplied to do so

Comment: George, your original attempt (even when updated according to Patrick’s suggestion) doesn’t work because of duplicated PXSelectorAttribute. Actually it’s not quite right to decorate InventoryID with PXSelectorAttribute due to Inventory CD being a segmented key - only PXDimensionSelectorAttribute is allowed for segmented keys.

Comment: Additional comment: repeating InventoryID with a separate AlternateID for each record in the selector will not let you achieve expected results and will only confuse users, as selector will always highlight first discovered Inventory CD despite selected AlternateID. Building a custom selector field against the INItemXRef DAC and populating Inventory ID in code also doesn’t seem to be possible: InventoryID is one of 5! key fields defined for the INItemXRef DAC. The solution suggested earlier seems to be the only acceptable option to get as close as possible to what customer requested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your Selector Search for InventoryID and then add a "SubstituteKey" option that will show the InventoryCD in the UI for the selector.  Example:  [PXSelector(typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryID), SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD))]